# Minimal polynomial of complex numbers over field

Tags: abstract-algebra, minimal-polynomials

> Find the minimal polynomial of complex numbers over the given field
>
> (i) $1+i$, over $\mathbb{Q}$

$[\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}]=2$, so $\deg(f)=2$.
$\alpha=1+i \rightarrow \alpha^2=2i $, so $f=x^2-2x+2$

> (ii) $-3+ \sqrt{7}$ over $\mathbb{R}$

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 7):\mathbb{R}]=1$ so it's $f=x+3-\sqrt 7$

> (iii) $\frac{1+ \sqrt{5} }{2}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

$[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 5):\mathbb{Q}]=2$ so $f=x^2-\frac{1}{2}x-1$

> (iv) $e^{ \frac{2\pi i}{5}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

I found polynomial $f=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ but how to show that is minimal?

> (v) $e^{ \frac{2\pi i}{5}}$ over $\mathbb{Q}( \sqrt{5})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(iv): Eisenstein on $f(x+1)$

(v): $2\cos\dfrac{2\pi}5=\dfrac{\sqrt5-1}2$

Comment: Item (iv) in particular has been handled many times on our site. For a general odd prime $p$, not just $p=5$. Item (v) is part of a general result telling that the unique quadratic subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/p})$ is
$\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*})$, where $p^*=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$.